# How do I load Javascript within jQuery based tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have Jquery and CSS tab like [this one](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/examples/tabs/) and in the each tab I have [facebook feed box](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/activity/), [twitter widget](http://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets), and my blog's ranking widget.  BUT if I place these widgets within the tab area content, each widgets stops working.  How do I get these widgets to load with in these jQuery tabs?

My tabs: http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/examples/tabs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [jQuery.getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

```
$.getScript('js-url', function(){
    //the loading is completed
    //display button
});
```

Hope this helps!

**Update:**

```
$.getScript('http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js', function(){ 
   //code 
});
```

Also, you can embed the iframe code version of twitter and facebook buttons instead of loading the js code each time, for example:

```
<iframe allowtransparency="true" 
        frameborder="0" 
        scrolling="no" 
        src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.html" 
        style="width:130px; height:50px;"></iframe>
```

Comment: so do i add the jquery tab code in 'js-url' or twitter widget code?

Comment: the twitter widget javascript url as an example